# How can I apply hover styles to a div when I hover another element?

Tags: jquery, html, css

What I want is to activate the hover also when I hover the mouse in the name (.teste), however I wanted to do this with jQuery.

```css
li .caixa {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #9d9d9d;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 210px;
  width: 210px;
  position: relative;
}

li .hover {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 8px;
  transition: .3s;
}

li .hover a,
span {
  display: none;
}

li .hover:hover {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #72adde;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<li>
  <div class="caixa">
    <img src="" alt=""><i class="flaticon-people"></i>

    <div class="hover">
      <a class="branco" href="">Ver Perfil </a>
      <span class="branco"> |</span>
      <a class="preto" href=""> Editar</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p><a class="teste" href="">Leona Lima</a></p>
</li>
```

Comment: in this case isn't it possible to wrap everything in the a tag and just do the hover on the a element? make things more easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - using jquery's hover method:

```js
$('.teste').hover(function() {
  $('.hover').addClass('active');
}, function() {
  $('.hover').removeClass('active');
});
```

```css
li .caixa {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #9d9d9d;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 210px;
  width: 210px;
  position: relative;
}

li .hover {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 8px;
  transition: .3s;
}

li .hover a,
span {
  display: none;
}

li .hover:hover {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #72adde;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.hover.active {
  background-color: #72adde;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
  <div class="caixa">
    <img src="" alt=""><i class="flaticon-people"></i>

    <div class="hover">
      <a class="branco" href="">Ver Perfil </a>
      <span class="branco"> |</span>
      <a class="preto" href=""> Editar</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p><a class="teste" href="">Leona Lima</a></p>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could toggle the css when hovering over link.

```
$('.teste').hover(function() { // mouseEnter callback
  // do whatever to box
}, function() { // mouseExit callback
  // undo whatever to box
});
```

a better solution might be to make another class to apply background color directly.

```
// css
.changeBackground {
  background-color: #72adde;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

$('.teste, .hover').toggleClass('.changeBackground');
```

Answer (score 0):

This will probably be better handled in CSS like you have done for your `.hover` class, but if it needed to be done in JavaScript or jQuery you can use the `.hover()` jQuery mouse event https://api.jquery.com/hover/

```
$(".teste").hover(function() {
  $(this).css("color", "red"); // or anything you want to trigger on your hover event
});
```

Comment: There's no support for the parent selector in CSS currently, nor a previous sibling selector, so it's not possible in CSS with OP's current markup.

Comment: Yes, with css I know how to do, I wanted to learn the same with jQuery to study, thank you very much for the solution!

Answer (score 0):

Without any javascript. Just change the "li .hover:hover" to "li:hover .hover" if you don't like it to set it on the whole li element just create a container element that holds the elements you want to hover.

I always recommend the non-js above the js method. But if you want really go with the jquery option I recommend the solution with the class change from Aquila Sagitta.

```css
li .caixa {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #9d9d9d;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 210px;
  width: 210px;
  position: relative;
}

li .hover {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 8px;
  transition: .3s;
}

li .hover a,
span {
  display: none;
}

li:hover .hover {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #72adde;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.hover.active {
  background-color: #72adde;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
  <div class="caixa">
    <img src="" alt=""><i class="flaticon-people"></i>

    <div class="hover">
      <a class="branco" href="">Ver Perfil </a>
      <span class="branco"> |</span>
      <a class="preto" href=""> Editar</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p><a class="teste" href="">Leona Lima</a></p>
</li>
```

Comment: Yes, with css I knew, I wanted to do the same with jQuery. Thank you very much for the solution!